# How to reference java node name?

Tags: java, javafx

How could I code the node below so that I can change the j in brick_Rowsj as per example below

```
brick_Rowsj.getChildren().add(imageview_tile1);
```

where j = 0 to 24

i.e.

```
brick_Rows0.getChildren().add(imageview_tile1);
brick_Rows1.getChildren().add(imageview_tile1);
brick_Rows2.getChildren().add(imageview_tile1);
```

...

Comment: Why not use a list or array?

Comment: how can i do this please?

Comment: I assume you wrote the class behind `brick_Rows` which due to the code you posted seems to contain a collection named `children`. Hence you should be familiar with that already, if not use the net to get some tutorials. The rest is more or less a matter of looking at the `List` api and JavaDocs.

Comment: @Thomas it's probably a subclass of [`Pane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html), but the OP should show enough code that we don't have to assume that. It would also help to know how all these instances are initialized.

Answer (score 1):

With use of arrays you can

```
Brick_Rows[] rows = new Brick_Rows[24];

brick_Rows[j].getChildren().add(imageview_tile1);
```

Comment: how do i define Brick_Rows[] rows = new Brick_Rows[24];

Comment: I assumed 'brick_Rows' reference type(Class Type) is Brick_Rows, And assumed your 'j' value is 24.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to create a container that contains all nodes, and then iterate over that container:

```
List<BrickRow> brickRows = Arrays.asList(brick_Rows0, brick_Rows1,  brick_rows2);
for (BrickRow brickRow : brickRows) {
    brickRow.getChildren().add(imageview_tile1);
}
```

Comment: thanks. but you code calls all the nodes at once, how can i call with a "j" variable

Comment: i am using this in a for loop

Comment: @Ossama `brickRows.get(i).getChildren(). ...` or to create new nodes: `brickRows.add( new BrickRow() )` (or alternatively initialize the list with null values and then call `brickRows.set(i, new BrickRow())` ).